# How to make a web request from within Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Running under local development, I'm trying to make a WebRequest to http://127.0.0.1:8000 under Windows Azure (July CTP).

But it throws a **"A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network 127.0.0.1:8000"** exception.

I have 2 web roles running from the same Cloudservice but with different port numbers. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine.  Are you sure you have something listening on port 8000?  Can you try accessing it from outside your Windows Azure application?

Comment: I can't access it from outside as well. Looks like the webrole didn't run when I unticked "Launch Browser" for it. Whoops. It's ok now. Thanks.